# Pass multiple arguments to single mixin argument

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I know it's possible to pass multiple arguments into a mixin function. Like so:

```
@mixin exampleOne($font-family, $primary-color){
  .address {
    font-family: $font-family;
    color: $primary-color;
  }
}
```

However, I would like to achieve something like this

```
@mixin exampleTwo($font-family, $primary-color...){
  .address {
    font-family: $font-family;
    color: $primary-color;
  }
}
```

So it would compiled:

`@include exampleTwo('Avenir', Red, font-weight: 600, text-transform: upperscase)`

To:

```
.address {
  font-family: 'Avenir';
  color: red;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I guess my question is, "Is it possible to pass extra arguments to a mixin, when that mixin has not yet defined those arguments. Just for extendibility. I don't think it's possible to pass an actual "Object" to a mixin argument. If you can that would answer my question."

Hope this makes sense.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do in this case would be to use a [map](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) to hold the property/value pairs, like:

```
(font-weight: 600, text-transform: uppercase)
```

Then you could add a parameter to hold the map in the mixin:

```
@mixin fonts($font-family, $primary-color, $styles){
```

And loop through, the map, inserting the styles into the rule:

```
@each $property, $value in $styles {
  #{$property}: $value;
}
```

To put it all together:

```
@mixin fonts($font-family, $primary-color, $styles){
  .address {
    font-family: $font-family;
    color: $primary-color;

    //Loop through styles map
    @each $property, $value in $styles {
      #{$property}: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

And you'd call it like:

```
@include exampleTwo('Avenir', Red, (font-weight: 600, text-transform: uppercase));
```

Which would output:

```
.address {
  font-family: "Avenir";
  color: Red;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[**SassMeister Demo**](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/565517c101531cf067ba11d58e12cf2a)

Comment: I never knew about that! Thank you so much!